# Oracle case statement not working

Tags: oracle

I want to use `case` statement for a column like below

```
SELECT   sr_no, TYPE, stage, party_name, amount, remarks, exp_type, exp_id,
     voucher_no, cheque_no, cheque_dt, chq_favr_name, attachment,
      CASE NVL (amount, 0) = 0 THEN checkVal = 0
      ELSE
      checkVal = 1
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_expense_info
 WHERE mkey = '354'
 AND ((NVL (amount, 0) <> 0) OR (party_name IS NOT NULL))          
ORDER BY sr_no
```

But I am getting error as

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   sr_no, TYPE, stage, party_name, amount, remarks, exp_type, exp_id,
     voucher_no, cheque_no, cheque_dt, chq_favr_name, attachment,
      CASE WHEN NVL(amount, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS checkVal
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_expense_info
 WHERE mkey = '354'
 AND ((NVL (amount, 0) <> 0) OR (party_name IS NOT NULL))          
ORDER BY sr_no
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing an END

```
SELECT   sr_no, TYPE, stage, party_name, amount, remarks, exp_type, exp_id,
     voucher_no, cheque_no, cheque_dt, chq_favr_name, attachment,
      CASE WHEN NVL (amount, 0) = 0 THEN checkVal = 0
      ELSE
      checkVal = 1
      END
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_expense_info
 WHERE mkey = '354'
 AND ((NVL (amount, 0) <> 0) OR (party_name IS NOT NULL))          
ORDER BY sr_no
```

Comment: there was a WHEN missing, i have corrected my answer

Comment: `THEN checkval = 0` ... that's wrong; you'd need to move the column alias (which I assume is `checkval`) to after the `END` and remove the `checkval =` from both clauses inside the case expression.